# The (non-existent?) retag button

Tags: discussion, retagging

I received the privilege to retag questions a while ago, but I couldn't seem to find the button used for this, as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions).

It seems to me that this is now just a normal part of editing. If so, I'd suggest that the information in the link above be modified to avoid confusion.

[image: What happens when I hover over tags]

Comment: See also: [I don't see the “retag” button anymore?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9673/49437)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The text is already corrected at the source wiki on MSO (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions). It should be synced to the privileges page at this site, but I'm not sure how often that happens. There is likely a manual process to push the changes to all sites, I've asked someone from SE to check on this.

Comment: One could fairly mark the wiki discrepancy as a bug (glad you mentioned it!).  This should be fixed in the very near future.

Answer (score 10):

The description of retagging on this site is out of date. Compare:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions (outdated)
- https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions (up to date)

Background reading: [Kill the Retag option, use just Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177265)